# switching from VB.net, ASP.net to Java is it a good idea?

Tags: java, asp.net

I am programmer analyst working mainly in Asp.net for more than 3 yrs. I always wondered why employers are ready to pay more dollars for the same skill a person have in dotnet. I also see more BPM technologies are based on Java. Like Pega, Tibco etc. I have learned java in my college 4-5 years back. but didnt do much.Please advise.

Thanks

Comment: It's never a bad idea to learn a new language on the side. But switching from a skillset you know to a technology you don't know seems a bit risky, especially given that you claim you can make more money in ASP.NET.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you can do in ASP.NET can also be done in Java, with the advantage of java being platform independent and more secure. You can learn and practice java but if you are a master of Dot Net, then you don't have to leave it unless and until required by a project.

Comment: @p.campbell http://onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2004/02/25/javavsdotnet.html + you have the fact that Microsoft made it...

Comment: @Lord: with respect, that's an article from 2004. Article written by a "member of BEA". I smell FUD.

Comment: @campbell: If I am wrong about Java being more secure then Asp.Net correct me, so that I won't make the same mistake again.

Answer (score 2):

You really haven't explained why you would want to switch to Java.

If you really want to work with BPM products like Pega and Tibco and you can only do that by switching your skillset to Java, then I would advise doing what will make you happy.  Nothing is worse than being in a job that you're unhappy or unsatisfied with -- it can be downright painful.  If you're happy in what you're doing, then you'll do a better job at it, which will make you more marketable and will reward you with a higher compensation (even if .NET developers are making more than Java as you say).

If you're only out of college a few years, then you're young enough to make a few changes in your career path and take some risks.  Do what makes you happy - it will pay off in the long run.  Don't just consider the money -- money will come if you do what makes you happy and you're good at what you do.

Just my 2 cents.  Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Switching of skill-set should depend upon various things like Company wants to shift technology, Your new projects requires it, you wish to add newer skillsets to your resume, etc. etc. can go on. I think is you should be doing whatever makes you and your pocket future safe and happy.

Technically with Java you can do whatever can be done using .net technologies. I am still not very clear about your reason, But if it is possible to go and change your skillset to Java without affecting your pocket and offcourse makes you happy, then go for it.